# Angular JS: What is the need of the directive’s link function when we already had directive’s controller with scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to perform some operations on scope and the template. It seems that I can do that in either the `link` function or the `controller` function (since both have access to the scope).

When is it the case when I have to use `link` function and not the controller?

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('abc', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) { /* link function */ },
        controller: function($scope, $element) { /* controller function */ }
    };
}
```

Also, I understand that `link` is the non-angular world. So, I can use `$watch`, `$digest` and `$apply`.

What is the significance of the `link` function, when we already had controller?

Comment: What do you mean by "_Also, I understand that link is the non-angular world. So, I can use `$watch`, `$digest` and `$apply`._" ?

Comment: Inside `link` we don't see any angular magic. i.e. no 2 way bindings, etc. Just that we have the angular's api available to use.

Answer (score 317, accepted):

After my **initial** struggle with the `link` and `controller` functions and reading quite a lot about them, I think now I have the answer.

First let's understand,

**How do AngularJS directives work in a nutshell:**

- We begin with a template (as a string or loaded to a string)

  `var templateString = '<div my-directive>{{5 + 10}}</div>';`
- Now, this `templateString` is wrapped as an **angular element**

  `var el = angular.element(templateString);`
- With `el`, now we compile it with `$compile` to get back the **link** function.

  `var l = $compile(el)`

  Here is what happens:

  - `$compile` walks through the whole template and collects all the directives that it recognizes.
  - All the directives that are discovered are **compiled recursively** and their `link` functions are collected.
  - Then, all the `link` functions are wrapped in a new `link` function and returned as `l`.
- Finally, we provide `scope` function to this `l` (link) function which further executes the wrapped link functions with this `scope` and their corresponding elements.

  `l(scope)`
- This adds the `template` as a new node to the `DOM` and invokes `controller` which adds its watches to the **scope** which is shared with the template in DOM.

[image]

Comparing **compile** vs **link** vs **controller** :

- Every directive is **compiled** only once and **link** function is retained for re-use. Therefore, if there's something applicable to all instances of a directive should be performed inside directive's `compile` function.
- Now, after compilation we have `link` function which is executed while attaching the **template** to the **DOM**. So, therefore we perform everything that is specific to every instance of the directive. For eg: **attaching events**, **mutating the template based on scope**, etc.
- Finally, the **controller** is meant to be available to be live and reactive while the directive works on the `DOM` (after getting attached). Therefore:

  (1) After setting up the view[**V**] (i.e. template) with link. `$scope` is our [**M**] and `$controller` is our [**C**] in **M V C**

  (2) Take advantage the **2-way** binding with **$scope** by setting up watches.

  (3) `$scope` watches are expected to be added in the controller since this is what is watching the template during run-time.

  (4) Finally, `controller` is also used to be able to communicate among related directives. (Like `myTabs` example in https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

  (5) It's true that we could've done all this in the `link` function as well but its about **separation of concerns**.

Therefore, finally we have the following which fits all the pieces perfectly:

[image: diagram showing compilation flow in AngularJS]

Comment: I've also found this article useful for understanding the order of execution here: [The nitty-gritty of compile and link functions inside AngularJS directives](http://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives/)

Comment: Great explanation. Would like to mention that the controller gets called before link function.

Comment: **controller is executed before link**

Answer (score 87):

### Why controllers are needed

The difference between `link` and `controller` comes into play when you want to nest directives in your DOM and expose API functions from the parent directive to the nested ones.

From the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> Best Practice: use controller when you want to expose an API to other directives. Otherwise use link.

Say you want to have two directives `my-form` and `my-text-input` and you want `my-text-input` directive to appear only inside `my-form` and nowhere else.

In that case, you will say while defining the directive `my-text-input` that it *requires* a controller from the `parent` DOM element using the require argument, like this: `require: '^myForm'`. Now the controller from the parent element will be `injected` into the `link` function as the fourth argument, following `$scope, element, attributes`. You can call functions on that controller and communicate with the parent directive.

Moreover, if such a controller is not found, an error will be raised.

### Why use link at all

There is no real need to use the `link` function if one is defining the `controller` since the `$scope` is available on the `controller`. Moreover, while defining both `link` and `controller`, one does need to be careful about the order of invocation of the two (`controller` is executed before).

However, in keeping with the *Angular way*, most DOM manipulation and 2-way binding using `$watchers` is usually done in the `link` function while the API for children and `$scope` manipulation is done in the `controller`. This is not a hard and fast rule, but doing so will make the code more modular and help in separation of concerns (controller will maintain the `directive` state and `link` function will maintain the `DOM` + outside bindings).

Comment: That's great. Now, can you help me with the second part of the question ?

Comment: I mean, since we had the controller in existence which could have been used to communicate with other directives. So, what was the need of `link` ?

Comment: Your answer somehow doesn't answers the actual question.

Comment: Are there any problems that occur when we define a `controller` ? Why will I want to invent a whole new function just to avoid defining controller ?

Comment: Updated the answer. No, I am not aware of any problems occurring in this case (though one does have to keep track of what order `controller` and `link` will be run). One _should_ keep `$scope` manipulation in `controller` and DOM manipulation (and 2-way binding using `$watch`ers) in `link` function, but that is a matter of weakly held opinions.

Comment: The problem is not with the excellent answer given by musically_ut. The problem is with the wording of the question. You dont have to anything but you ought to.

Comment: it seems that @scalaGirl s Link is not working anymore

Comment: @scalaGirl could you remove your link? it directs to a malicious website.

Comment: I'll try but seems like I can not unless i remove the whole comment so copying my original comment here and then deleting it from above. 
"From a practical perspective, you should always put your DOM manipulations in link, and business logic in the controller, which is more of the angular convention. Some people will put both of these exclusively in link, which is fine but somewhat violates the separation of concerns principle. Bottom line, putting DOM manipulations and business logic exclusively in link is “safer” than putting them exclusively in the controller."

Answer (score 19):

The `controller` function/object represents an abstraction model-view-controller (MVC). While there is nothing new to write about MVC, it is still the most significant advanatage of angular: split the concerns into smaller pieces. And that's it, nothing more, so if you need to react on `Model` changes coming from `View` the `Controller` is the right *person* to do that job.

The story about `link` function is different, it is coming from different perspective then MVC.  And is really essential, once we want to cross the boundaries of a `controller/model/view` *(template)*.

Let' start with the parameters which are passed into the `link` function:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {
```

- **scope** is an Angular scope object.
- **element** is the jqLite-wrapped element that this directive matches.
- **attrs** is an object with the normalized attribute names and their corresponding values.

To put the `link` into the context, we should mention that all directives are going through this initialization process steps: *Compile*, *Link*. An Extract from *Brad Green and Shyam Seshadri book Angular JS*:

**Compile phase** (a sister of link, let's mention it here to get a clear picture):

*In this phase, Angular walks the DOM to identify all the registered
 directives in the template. For each directive, it then transforms the
 DOM based on the directive’s rules (template, replace, transclude, and
 so on), and calls the compile function if it exists. The result is a
 compiled template function,*

**Link phase**:

> To make the view dynamic, Angular then runs a link function for each
>   directive. The link functions typically creates listeners on the DOM
>   or the model. These listeners keep the view and the model in sync at
>   all times.

A nice example how to use the `link` could be found here: [Creating Custom Directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). See the example: **Creating a Directive that Manipulates the DOM**, which inserts a "date-time" into page, refreshed every second.

Just a very short snippet from that **rich** source above, showing the real manipulation with DOM. There is hooked function to $timeout service, and also it is cleared in its *destructor* call to avoid memory leaks

```
.directive('myCurrentTime', function($timeout, dateFilter) {

 function link(scope, element, attrs) {

 ...

 // the not MVC job must be done
 function updateTime() {
   element.text(dateFilter(new Date(), format)); // here we are manipulating the DOM
 }

 function scheduleUpdate() {
   // save the timeoutId for canceling
   timeoutId = $timeout(function() {
     updateTime(); // update DOM
     scheduleUpdate(); // schedule the next update
   }, 1000);
 }

 element.on('$destroy', function() {
   $timeout.cancel(timeoutId);
 });

 ...
```

Comment: You seem to have compared `compiler` and `link`. They question is asking why `link` when we already had `controller`

Comment: I've extended the answer to describe even the controller in more details. Now the concepts of the `controller` vs `link` should be more clear...

Comment: Hi, you have functions like `updateTime` in link function which goes against the `Best Practice` to expose API's in controller. Also, your answer is logical (reasonable) but can you site some official documentation/video tutorial for the vision of link function vs controller function ??

Comment: The code snippet comes from here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive, There you can find all the details. and it is for sure official ;) The `updateTime` is not API of the directive. It is internal directive method.

Comment: I can sought of settle for that explanation. But it seems to be kind of blurry there. It would be great if someone from angular team itself can speak for it, projecting where do they see it going - to the `link` or the `controller`.

Comment: Have you went through that link? The answer is there. I would say, read it, it is not so long. And at the end, you will see that... finall cite: "use controller when you want to expose an API to other directives. Otherwise use link"

Comment: I can see that you borrowed this snippet from official angular website. Isn't it possible to do everything inside the controller itself ?
If I forget about the `link` for sometime ?

Comment: Also, anything on the `$watch`, `$digest` and `$apply` part of the question ?

Comment: I am trying to say: If you are thinking about the problem beeing solved wiht the directive: Could it be done as MVC? the best candidate is the `controller`. Anything more specific (cooperation among directives, direct access to DOM)... it is the `link`. So, you can live with controller only. But you should keep in mind, that once it is not sufficient... link is there for us; )

Comment: That is the only part I want to understand ( When is it not sufficient ? ). Plus, I get all benefits of angular in `controller` and `link` is relatively ugly. So, angular team must have a good reason for it instead of just an option.

Comment: Question: When Controller is not sufficient? Ans: When you need an out of Angular experience, such as to use a JQuery plugin or use JQlite feature as mentioned in the document( https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element:), then you would need link