# Angular share data from directive controller to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to know if there is any way to share data from directive controller to controller without events.
lets say i have:

```
.directive('someHandler', function () {
    return {
      controller: function () {
        this.users = [];
      }
    }
  })
```

This is parent directive that responsible to his children directives communication.
I want every time lets say this array change to let know the main controller. 
Like the functionality of "=";

Comment: The child directives can `require` the parent. Angular will pass an instance of the parent controller as the 4th argument to the child's `link` function. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Yes but i want it not in the children. I want it on the mainController. The controller of the view.

Comment: sounds like your `users`is a model for the directive. Then define it as such. Do not create `users` in the directive. Use `ngModel`

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea, hope it will work. Try to use the controller of directive

```
.directive('someHandler', function () {
    return {
     //...previous arguments
     controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.YourFunction = function () {
               //Your code
            }
    }
  });
```

and then to call **$scope.YourFunction()** in your controller.

**ADDITION**

if you want to use the function from parent directive, you must include the **require** argument in child directive. In this way, you make a hierarchical relationship and enable the communication between them.

After that, you must use link function to call the function from parent controller.

In your case, the child directive will look like:

```
.directive('childsomeHandler', function () {
    return {
     //...previous arguments
     require:"^someHandler", //here is inheritance to make communication between child and parent diretctive

   link: function (scope, element, attrs, someHandlerCtrl) {
       someHandlerCtrl.YourFunction();
    }
  });
```

Reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018507/angularjs-what-is-the-need-of-the-directives-link-function-when-we-already-had), you will know when to use link and controllers.
For more details, read this great article:
https://thinkster.io/egghead/directive-communication/

In the end, I hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: But how i use this function in the childs directives?

Comment: I made addition to my post.