# Adding variables to object returned from directive declaration

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is it possible to attach a "custom property" to an object returned from factory method in directive without the need of assigning value to a scope property from element's attribute?

Ex.

Directive declaration:

```
(...).directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            example: '@'
        },
        template: '<p>{{customProperty}}</p>' +
                  '<p>{{example}}</p>',
        customProperty: 'Hello'; // is this possible ???
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<div>
    <my-directive example="Example variable value"></my-directive>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not immediately clear what you're asking. Can you please edit your question and be more specific?

Comment: That question was basically about link function that is able to register new properties on scope. This answers my queston http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018507/angularjs-what-is-the-need-of-the-directives-link-function-when-we-already-had . Also great ng-conf talk that answers a lot of directive's related questions https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMkd0nYmLzY