# Unable to manipulate inherited scope in directive link (konami code directive implementation)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Edit: working plunker of this directive (includes solution):**
http://embed.plnkr.co/UhFCVa/

Trying to create a directive to enable a debug mode by listening to keystrokes. It properly reaches the "debug mode toggle" message, so I understand my use of the scope object is wrong. Can't figure what I've missed since the "showDebug" variable is made available in the scope, but it's not updated:

```
app.directive('bpKonamiDebug', ['$document', '$rootScope',

    function($document, $rootScope) {

        // Pattern = Konami code (↑ ↑ ↓ ↓ ← → ← → B A)
        var pattern = [38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 66, 65];

        // Pattern = "debug"
        // var pattern = [100, 101, 98, 117, 103]; // keycodes for "debug"

        var cursor = 0;

        return {

            restrict: 'A',

            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

                // Enrich parent scope

                // stackoverflow: This is where the variable is set (works)

                scope.showDebug = true;

                // Bind document's keydown event (rem: keypress is trapped by navigation handler, pans the screen and disables propagation)
                $document.bind('keydown', function(event) {

                    // Obtain keycode
                    var keycode = event.which;

                    // Compare keycode with expected character
                    if(pattern[cursor] == keycode){

                        // End of the pattern?
                        if(pattern.length == ++cursor){

                            console.log('debug mode toggle');

                            // stackoverflow: This is where I fail to change the value

                            scope.showDebug = !scope.showDebug;
                            cursor = 0;
                        }
                    }

                    else{

                        cursor = 0;
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found that the logic in "link" is executed as the directive is attached to the dom.

Read this answer for a good explanation: 
[AngularJS: What is the need of the directive's link function when we already had directive's controller with scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018507/angularjs-what-is-the-need-of-the-directives-link-function-when-we-already-had)

In my case, the event just seems to need a scope.$apply() call.