# Hide the div on button click

Tags: angularjs

I have created a custom directive to show the error messages in the page. My directive is

```
app.directive('errorsection', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            errors: '=errors'
        },
        templateUrl: '..../shared/error-section.html'
    };
});
```

**error-section.html**

```
<div ng-show="errors.length>0" class="error">
    <div id="{{error.Id}}" ng-class="{'error':error.Type=='Error','alert-info alert-dismissible cssDataTargetDismiss-{{error.Id}} fade in':error.Type=='Info'}" ng-repeat="error in errors track by $index">
        <button ng-if="error.Type=='Info'" type="button" class="close" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".cssDataTargetDismiss-{{alert.Id}}">×</button>
        <p><strong ng-bind-html="error.TypeDescription"></strong><span ng-bind-html="error.Message"></span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have used this directive in one of my partial page to show the error messages

```
<div error-section errors="errorList"></div>
```

this errorList contains 2 messages. If I click the button, message is collapsed. I want to hide the `div` if all the error messages collapsed. error messages is showing in view like below format,

```
     ______________
 |error1       x|
 |error2       x|
  _______________
```

How can I hide the `div` if all the messages collapsed?

Answer (score 0):

You can check a counter to do your job -

```
<div ng-show="errors.length>0 && clickCount !== errors.length" class="error">
    <div id="{{error.Id}}" ng-class="{'error':error.Type=='Error','alert-info alert-dismissible cssDataTargetDismiss-{{error.Id}} fade in':error.Type=='Info'}"
     ng-repeat="error in errors track by $index">
    <button data-ng-click="clickCount = clickCount + 1" ng-if="error.Type=='Info'" type="button" class="close" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".cssDataTargetDismiss-{{alert.Id}}">×</button>
    <p><strong ng-bind-html="error.TypeDescription"></strong><span ng-bind-html="error.Message"></span></p> </div>
```

Note - with in your **link** function, initialize your **clickCount** as

```
scope.clickCount = 0;
```

**directive**

```
app.directive('errorsection', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            errors: '=errors'
        },
        templateUrl: '..../shared/error-section.html',
        link : function(scope, elem, attr) {
            scope.clickCount  = 0;
        }
    };
});
```

To sum up -

Step 1 - initialize your clickCount to 0 in your link function

Step 2 - change the ng-if condition to use the click count

Step 3 - change the ng-click to increment the clickCount

hope this helps.

Comment: here what is meant by link function

Comment: to understand the link function read - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018507/angularjs-what-is-the-need-of-the-directives-link-function-when-we-already-had, http://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives/

Comment: added the link function to your directive.

Comment: plz create a plunk / jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve that:

First modify your directive as:

```
app.directive('errorSection', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            errors: '=errors'
        },
        templateUrl: '..../shared/error-section.html',
        link: function ($scope) {
            $scope.$watch('errors', function (value) {
                if (value) {
                    var count = 0;
                    angular.forEach(value, function(error) {
                        if (error.collapsed) {
                            count ++;
                        }
                    });

                    $scope.errorsCount = value.length;
                    $scope.collapsedErrorsCount = count;
                } else {
                    $scope.errorsCount = 0;
                    $scope.collapsedErrorsCount = 0;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Now modify your HTML as:

```
<div ng-show="errorsCount > 0 && errorsCount != collapsedErrorsCount" class="error">
    <div id="{{error.Id}}" ng-show="!error.collapsed"
         ng-class="{'error':error.Type=='Error','alert-info alert-dismissible cssDataTargetDismiss-{{error.Id}} fade in':error.Type=='Info'}"
         ng-repeat="error in errors track by $index">

        <button ng-if="error.Type=='Info'" type="button" class="close" ng-click="error.collapsed = true">×
        </button>

        <p><strong ng-bind-html="error.TypeDescription"></strong><span ng-bind-html="error.Message"></span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is what happening:

1. Since your `errors` is a list of objects, so instead of manually collapsing the values, we are using another key `collapsed` for those error objects to hide the each particular `div` using `ng-show="!error.collapsed"`
2. Then we added a `$watch` to your `errors` object list which will be called whenever your values changed in the `errors` object. This will maintain two counts i.e. the number of total errors and number of total errors which are collapsed.
3. Now whenever you collapse an error div, your watch expression will be called and the two counts will be updated. Now based on the two counts, your parent `div` will be hidden from the expression: `ng-show="errorsCount > 0 && errorsCount != collapsedErrorsCount" class="error"`