# wired scope of `ng-init` aside custom directive using different scope definition

Tags: angularjs, directive, ng-init

This is from angular doc about `ng-init`.

> The ngInit directive allows you to evaluate an expression in the current scope.

But if I use `ng-init` along with custom directive, and the directive use different scope difinition, the variable by `ng-init` will have different scope.

[demo](http://codepen.io/maple-leaf/pen/Bjyeaz?editors=101)

```
<body ng-app="transcludeScope" ng-init="test='test'">
    <div truescope ng-init="test2='test2'">Transcluded:<p>test: {{test}}</p><p>test2: {{test2}}</p><p>test3: {{test3}}</p></div>
    <hr>
    <div isolatescope ng-init="test3='test3'">Transcluded:<p>test: {{test}}</p><p>test2: {{test2}}</p><p>test3: {{test3}}</p></div>
    </div>
</body>



angular.module('transcludeScope', [])
.directive('truescope', function() {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    scope: true,
    template: "<p>test: {{test}}</p><p>test2: {{test2}}</p><div ng-transclude></div>"
  }
})
.directive('isolatescope', function() {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    scope: {},
    template: "<p>test: {{test}}</p><p>test3: {{test3}}</p><div ng-transclude></div>"
  }
});
```

From the result, `test2` is only available inside directive while `test3` is available whole app.

can anyone explain their behavior? Thanks :-)

Comment: You completely ignored the gigantic red warning message on that documentation page that you copied your description from.  `ngInit` is a directive, priority 450, which means that it may have undesired side effects when interacting with other directives, especially ones which have a lower priority, or create a child scope themselves.

Comment: @Claies I follow the warning suggest in ng doc in real project code, this problem is happen when I create a demo code to explain directive's scope, which I don't use any controller because the demo is very simple to use controller.

Comment: @Claies maybe it is a side effect...

Comment: I actually don't think this is related to `ngInit`, but related to how `transclude` interacts with `scope : { }`.  This may give you more insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653004/confused-about-angularjs-transcluded-and-isolate-scopes-bindings

Comment: @tjfdfs This may also help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34038699/why-directive-has-scope

Comment: @BhojendraNepal thanks