# Find element in angular template from controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working with a directive.
Here is simple format of my directive:

```
angular.module('app',[]).directive('companylookup', CompanyLookupDirective);

function CompanyLookupDirective() {
    return {
        templateUrl: '<input id="foo"/>',            
        controller: 'CompanyLookupController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    }
}
```

I want to find input element with jquery in my controller (CompanyLookupController.js) like this:

```
var foo =    $('#foo');
// decorate foo element using igniteui lib
$('#foo').igCombo({ datasource: ...});
```

But $('#foo') always return null. I can try to delay finding element with $timeout service to wait until element exist. But I don't want to do this so much times in my app in concern of performance.

Is there any way we can reference template elements in angularjs from a controller?

Comment: Don't do that. If you need to work with DOM from controller, it's almost always a sign of bad design. Controller should be DOM-agnostic. Using $timeout service this is even worse, please don't do that. For DOM operations, there's a link function (or compile, but you don't usually want to use that).

Comment: you should query the DOM using the element argument in the directive's link function.

Comment: @RobertGoldwein: I see many cases which we need find an element in view. I use igCombo, and and want to start it (set config for the element) from my controller. Example code with igniteui: $('#foo').igCombo({ datasource: ...}); Could  you suggest any idea to improve the way to deal with this problem.

Comment: Please don't take it in a bad way - this is that bad design - this way, in controller you deal directly with the view - you should change model in controller. If you'd need to mix jQ stuff, do it in directive - write own simple directive that wraps that jQ plugin and perform init/change things in directive. Not only this is far better, but you can reuse this directive later. There are many, many jQ-wrapping directives (unfortunately).

Comment: @RobertGoldwein: Thank you so much. I will think about your suggestion with directive for my project.

Answer (score 0):

in template URL use escape character before quotes ,

```
templateUrl: '<input id=\"foo\"></input>'
```

Also i agree with @Robert Goldwein and if you absolutely have to, use [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018507/angularjs-what-is-the-need-of-the-directives-link-function-when-we-already-had) to manipulate DOM

**EDIT :**  [Help](http://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives/) on link and compile functions.

Comment: Thank you, from your answer, I also found a similar way in controller (I inject element in my controller) like that: 
    function LookupController($element) {
   var fooElement = $($element).find('#foo');
 }

Comment: hmm, see in controller is a place where you put directive logic...linking in phase where you attach your dom elements and it returns you the linked html...compile is a place where compilation "thingy" happens, as in it finds which element is your directive attached to and returns a template function, SO if you want to manipulate the dom DO NOT use controller(not saying you cant rather avoid it).