# is it mandatory to have a link function in angularjs directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

When building our own directives in angularjs 1.5.x+, is it mandatory to have a link function? If not, how will angular deal with it? Will it use its own default implementation of the link function?
I explored a lot about this. However little information is available in the search engines in this regard.

Comment: this may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018507/angularjs-what-is-the-need-of-the-directives-link-function-when-we-already-had

Comment: why don't you try it without a link function?>

Comment: Hi Harry/deoD...thanks for the quick reply. dioD, This link says it is ok not to have a link function but does not specify the details of how it is handled internally. @Harry, I tried and it worked. However, would like to know the internal behavior while the link function is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No.

You do not have to use the link function. It's typically used if your directive wants to modify the DOM or needs to hook into events on the component related to the directive. Some directives might not need this, and even if you just want to work with a template and a scope, you still don't need to use the link function.

It's all very well explained here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

You can use the controller function instead of the link in many cases. Taken directly from the docs:

> The basic difference is that controller can expose an API, and link
>   functions can interact with controllers using require.

Comment: That helps...thanks a lot....I tried without using the link function and it worked for me...what I wanted to know is if we do not use the link function how it is handled internally. Seems if the link function is not present angular will simply ignore it.