# Which is preferable controller or link function in AngularJS directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

#### Angular docs said:

> **Best Practice**: use controller when you want to expose an API to other directives. Otherwise use link.

Why should we use link functions if we don't have any APIs to expose from the directive and if there is no data to share between the directives?

Comment: You know that a API can also delivered by an object or function (for example jQuery or any other library which delivers you methods and functions)? API does not mean to have a service running like `HTTP APIs` which communicate with foreign systems.

Comment: @lin, Yes. But, what I mean is if I don't expose any APIs  from the directive like functions or data, then why we should not use controller.

Comment: API also includes any functions to share between directives

Comment: @Sai, I have the same doubt. Why can't we use controllers instead, If there are no APIs to expose from the directive or if there is no data to share.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: What is the need of the directive's link function when we already had directive's controller with scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018507/angularjs-what-is-the-need-of-the-directives-link-function-when-we-already-had)

Comment: Also, testing cannot get into the link function, whereas a controller is straightforward to test.

Comment: @rrd, Then we should use controller. But, docs says use link function.

Comment: I'm speaking from commercial experience, TDD has a much easier path testing directives if you use controllers instead of the link function. If you don't want to test, then stick your logic in the link function, if you do - use the controller.

Comment: @lin, Is there any performance changes in using any of them?

Comment: No, it does depend on how your logic is implemented. You could create aweful controllers or directives but also awesome controllers and direcitves. But thats an other chapter... =)