# Which function will execute first in angularjs directives? link or controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have gone through this link https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/07/07/practical-guide-to-prelink-postlink-and-controller-methods-of-angular-directives/, they said the order(first to last) of execution of link and controller is

1. Controller,
2. Pre-Link function,
3. Post-Link function

But here I read [AngularJS: What is the need of the directive's link function when we already had directive's controller with scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018507/angularjs-what-is-the-need-of-the-directives-link-function-when-we-already-had) link executes before the controller. Which one I should believe in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it was first `link` then `controller` it wouldn't be possible to `require` other directives and and use theirs controllers in `link` function.

Take a look at the code from [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile):

```
var directiveDefinitionObject = {
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude, otherInjectables) { ... },
    controllerAs: 'stringIdentifier',
    require: 'siblingDirectiveName', // requiring another directive       
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
      return {
         pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... }, //siblingDirectiveName's controller is available in link function 
         post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... }
      }          
    },
  };
  return directiveDefinitionObject;
});
```

To support this statement we can read o the same page :

> controller
>
> Controller constructor function. The controller is instantiated **before** the pre-linking phase and can be accessed by other directives (see require attribute). This allows the directives to communicate with each other and augment each other's behavior.